# Unity GameObject with list containing other objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a school project i'm working with Unity. Im making a "game" where you need to connect devices with cables.
So I have a object called "device" with a script "deviceController". The Device object has a List containing other objects with a script called "portController". 
Currently im trying to set a bool(anyCablesConnected) to true in the deviceController, if there are any cables in a port to a device and if there are no cables connected to the device set the bool to false. The portController also has a bool called "Occupied".

Only I have no idea how to do this. Do I use a foreach loop or something like that ?

```
foreach(port in device){
   // IF A PORT FROM A DEVICE IS OCCUPIED, SET ANYCABLESCONNECTED TO TRUE
   if (occupied == true){
       anyCablesConnected = true;
   } else {
       anyCablesConnected = false;
   }
}
```

Something like this ? I haven't really worked with foreach loops. But I hope you guys can help me !

Comment: How are you testing if a device is 'occupied'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `anyCablesConnected` should be true iff at least one cable is connected. The logic for that is:

```
anyCablesConnected = false;

foreach (var port in device)
{
    // IF A PORT FROM A DEVICE IS OCCUPIED, SET ANYCABLESCONNECTED TO TRUE
    if (port.GetComponent<portController>().occupied)
    {
        anyCablesConnected = true;

        // No need to continue looping, we have already found a cable
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can use LINQ for a more compact solution:

```
anyCablesConnected = device.Any(x => x.GetComponent<portController>().occupied);
```

Note that I have made some assumptions as to how your `occupied` flag is accessed!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, while writing the answer seems to have popped up. But to spare me deleting everything while giving you some context on how foreach works.

A list containing strings; `List<string>`, would be written like this:

```
List<string> listWithStrings = new List<string>();

listWithStrings.Add("Hello");
listWithStrings.Add("World");
```

and looped through with a foreach:

```
foreach (string stringInList in listWithStrings) {
    Debug.Log(stringInList); 
    // The first loop stringInList will be "Hello", 
    // the second loop it will be "World"
}
```

Which is pretty much the same as a standard for-loop would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listWithStrings.Count; i++) {
    Debug.Log(listWithStrings[i]);
}
```

But a lot easier and cleaner.